# How to automatically load text into Text area

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, bufferedreader

I have a program with a notepad esque functionality. When I open it, I want text which is saved from a text file to be automatically loaded onto the text area.

I have two classes. Writer class (where the saved text should be appear) and the Load class which actually imports text from text file.

Writer Class:

```
public class Writer extends Application {
private FlowPane notepadLayout = new FlowPane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
private Scene notepadScene = new Scene(notepadLayout,600,300);
private TextArea inputArea = new TextArea();

private void notepadSetup(){
Text titleText = new Text("Notepad");
notepadLayout.getChildren().add(titleText);
notepadLayout.getChildren().add(inputArea);
}

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
notepadSetup();

 Load.loadOperation(); 

primaryStage.setTitle("ROBOT V1!");
primaryStage.setScene(notepadScene);
primaryStage.show();
```

So the above class has the Text area. What I want to do is use the below class to load information from a textfile into the above text area.

```
public class Load {
private static String line;
static ArrayList<String> x = new ArrayList<>();

 public static void loadOperation(){
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("Notes.txt"));
        line = br.readLine();

        while(line != null){
             x.add(line);                
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    }catch(Exception e){

    }
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

The line Load.loadOperation prints out the contents in the text file. How do I make it load onto the text area? It has to also conserve formatting (line breaks).

Comment: Your code won't even compile.

Comment: @James_D it does now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the method so that it returns a String. (I updated it so that it uses more modern Java too.)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Load {

    public static String loadOperation() throws IOException {
            return Files.lines(Paths.get("Notes.txt"))
                .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));

    }
}
```

Then you just do

```
try {
    inputArea.setText(Load.loadOperation());
} catch (IOException exc) {
    exc.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Can I upload my Save class and you check to see if it's up to date and efficient ?

Comment: No, just read up on the API docs for the methods I used and look at other similar methods in the same classes.

Answer (score -1):

After you read the text from the file, you need to add it to the `TextArea` object. So assuming that you have a reference to `inputArea` handy, you could append it into the (empty) control:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    inputArea.appendText(x.get(i));
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html

Comment: The method is [`appendText(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-), not `append(...)`.

Comment: @James_D In the API documentation it lists both and says that `appendText(...)` is deprecated.

Comment: You're linking the API docs for an AWT text area. You can't use an AWT text area in a JavaFX application.